# "Export settings" disambiguation and meaning

Tags: meaning, grammar, ambiguity, disambiguation

"Export settings" disambiguation and meaning.

The aforementioned quotation is ambiguous. As I see it, it could mean either of the following:

1. Export (verb) settings ---> Action of exporting the settings
2. Export (adjectival noun) settings ---> Settings of export

Is there a way to disambiguate "export settings" or is the English language, in such cases, inherently ambiguous and the actual meaning has to be inferred from context?

Comment: Yes' ambiguity can arise, even with complete sentences. 'Flying aeroplanes can be dangerous' is a cracking example from Chomsky, though he doubtless used the American spelling. // Note that if 'export' is a verb here, the string is an imperative sentence. If 'export' is an attributive noun, the string is a noun phrase.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Very nice example!

Comment: A sentence which is "complete" does not necessarily have all the fixins that make it clear or unambiguous. The fact that some words or constructions can be shortened or omitted does not mean they should always be.

Answer (score 2):

English does not use many inflections and relies heavily on other grammatical devices to specify meaning within a clause. But you have not provided a complete clause.

There are of course instances where the syntax of a clause alone is insufficient to convey meaning, and the intended meaning is dependent on context, but usually the intended meaning of a clause can be determined by a combination of lexical meanings of individual words and the meaning of the overall syntax of the entire clause.

> The export settings can be adjusted easily.

The definite article “the” immediately preceding “export” and the verb form closely following “export” unambiguously indicate that “export” is intended as an adjective or noun rather than a verb.

> We export settings to thirty different countries.

The pronoun preceding “export” and the absence of any other verb form in the clause unambiguously indicate that “export” is intended as a verb.

It is possible to utter ambiguous clauses in English because the field of meaning of many English words is broad. But the syntax by which words are combined in a clause frequently eliminates such apparent lexical ambiguity. English has far less potential for ambiguity if you parse complete clauses rather than isolated phrases.

Comment: In this case, the "Export settings" sentence is from one of Microsoft Windows' menus. My opinion is that it could be either an incomplete nominative sentence or an imperative sentence. I am well aware of the ambiguity, but I wanted to know if there was a way to formulate sentences, in English, in a way so as to avoid such ambiguities.

Comment: The point is that microsoft menu selections are not formulated as sentences at all. “Copy” is neither a command to copy (a verb), nor a replica of something (a noun). It is an abbreviation indicating where to click to initiate a process. Such abbreviations have meaning in microsofts world, but are not models of how English is normally spoken.